# how to get selected rows value using wijmo flex grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, wijmo

Here I created the sample code for wijmo flex grid, its working fine, but the problem is how to get the selected row values?

```js
angular.module('app', ['wj']);



'use strict';

// declare app module
var app = angular.module('app');

// controller
app.controller('appCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    // create the filter and expose it to scope for customization
    $scope.initialized = function (s, e) {
        var flex = s;
        $scope.filter = new wijmo.grid.filter.FlexGridFilter(flex);
        $scope.downloadsColumnFilterType = wijmo.grid.filter.FilterType.Condition;
        $scope.$apply();
        $scope.filter.filterChanging.addHandler(function () {
            console.log('filter changing');
        });
        $scope.filter.filterChanged.addHandler(function () {
            console.log('filter changed');
        });
        $scope.filter.filterApplied.addHandler(function () {
            console.log('filter applied');
        });
    }

    // persist filter definition
    $scope.saveFilter = function () {
        localStorage['filter'] = $scope.filter.filterDefinition;
    }
    $scope.restoreFilter = function () {
        $scope.filter.filterDefinition = localStorage['filter'];
    }

    // update filter type for "downloads" column
    $scope.$watch('downloadsColumnFilterType', function () {
        var f = $scope.filter;
        if (f) {
            var col = f.grid.columns.getColumn('downloads'),
                cf = f.getColumnFilter(col, true);
            cf.filterType = $scope.downloadsColumnFilterType;
        }
    });

    // filters are localizable
    $scope.culture = 'en';
    $scope.$watch('culture', function () {

        // remove old localization reference
        var loc = document.getElementById('loc');
        if (loc) {
            document.head.removeChild(loc);
        }

        // add new localization reference
        loc = document.createElement('script');
        loc.id = 'loc';
        loc.type = 'text/javascript';
        loc.async = false;
        loc.src = 'scripts/vendor/wijmo.culture.' + $scope.culture + '.js';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(loc);

        // show changes
        invalidateAll();
    });

    // invalidate all Wijmo controls
    // using a separate function to handle strange IE9 scope issues
    function invalidateAll() {
        wijmo.Control.invalidateAll();
    }

    // create some random data
    var countries = 'US,Germany,UK,Japan,Italy,Greece'.split(','),
        data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        data.push({
            id: i,
            date: new Date(2015, i % 12, (i + 1) % 25),
            time: new Date(2015, i % 12, (i + 1) % 25, i % 24, i % 60, i % 60),
            country: countries[i % countries.length],
            countryMapped: i % countries.length,
            downloads: Math.round(Math.random() * 20000),
            sales: Math.random() * 10000,
            expenses: Math.random() * 5000,
            checked: i % 9 == 0
        });
    }
    $scope.data = new wijmo.collections.CollectionView(data);

    // notify scope when collectionView changes
    $scope.data.collectionChanged.addHandler(function () {
        if (!$scope.$root.$$phase) {
            $scope.$apply();
        }
    });

    // expose countries, country map
    $scope.countries = countries;
    var countryMap = [
        { name: 'US', key: 0 },
        { name: 'Germany', key: 1 },
        { name: 'Japan', key: 2 },
        { name: 'Italy', key: 3 },
        { name: 'Greece', key: 4 },
        { name: 'Spain', key: 5 },
        { name: 'Chile', key: 6 },
        { name: 'China', key: 7 },
        { name: 'Canada', key: 8 },
        { name: 'Astralia', key: 9 },
        { name: 'Austria', key: 10 }
    ];
    $scope.countryMap = new wijmo.grid.DataMap(new wijmo.collections.CollectionView(countryMap), 'key', 'name');

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
     <!-- Wijmo -->
     <script src="http://demos.wijmo.com/5/Angular/FlexGridFilter/FlexGridFilter/scripts/vendor/wijmo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="http://demos.wijmo.com/5/Angular/FlexGridFilter/FlexGridFilter/scripts/vendor/wijmo.grid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="http://demos.wijmo.com/5/Angular/FlexGridFilter/FlexGridFilter/scripts/vendor/wijmo.grid.filter.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  
    <script src="http://demos.wijmo.com/5/Angular/FlexGridFilter/FlexGridFilter/scripts/vendor/wijmo.input.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  
    <link href="http://demos.wijmo.com/5/Angular/FlexGridFilter/FlexGridFilter/styles/vendor/wijmo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Wijmo-Angular interop -->
    <script src="http://demos.wijmo.com/5/Angular/FlexGridFilter/FlexGridFilter/scripts/vendor/wijmo.angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
    
    
    
  </head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
 
    
        <wj-flex-grid
            style="height:300px"
            initialized="initialized(s, e)"
            items-source="data">
                <wj-flex-grid-column header="ID" binding="id"></wj-flex-grid-column>
                <wj-flex-grid-column header="Date" binding="date" format='MMM/dd/yyyy'></wj-flex-grid-column>
                <wj-flex-grid-column header="Time" binding="time" format="t"></wj-flex-grid-column>
                <wj-flex-grid-column header="Country" binding="country"></wj-flex-grid-column>
                <wj-flex-grid-column header="Country ID" binding="countryMapped" data-map="countryMap"></wj-flex-grid-column>
                <wj-flex-grid-column header="Downloads" binding="downloads"></wj-flex-grid-column>
                <wj-flex-grid-column header="Sales" binding="sales"></wj-flex-grid-column>
                <wj-flex-grid-column header="Expenses" binding="expenses"></wj-flex-grid-column>
                <wj-flex-grid-column header="Checked" binding="checked"></wj-flex-grid-column>
        </wj-flex-grid>
      
        
         
         
    </div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the FlexGrid's selectedItems property, as well as the selectedRows and selection properties if you'd like, to access the row values.  selectedItems is probably the easiest way to access the underlying data items, and below is a modified version of your sample that logs the selected data items to the console.

```js
angular.module('app', ['wj']);



'use strict';

// declare app module
var app = angular.module('app');

// controller
app.controller('appCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.ctx = {
      grid: null
    };

    // create the filter and expose it to scope for customization
    $scope.initialized = function (s, e) {
        var flex = s;
        $scope.filter = new wijmo.grid.filter.FlexGridFilter(flex);
        $scope.downloadsColumnFilterType = wijmo.grid.filter.FilterType.Condition;
        $scope.$apply();
        $scope.filter.filterChanging.addHandler(function () {
            console.log('filter changing');
        });
        $scope.filter.filterChanged.addHandler(function () {
            console.log('filter changed');
        });
        $scope.filter.filterApplied.addHandler(function () {
            console.log('filter applied');
        });
    }

    // persist filter definition
    $scope.saveFilter = function () {
        localStorage['filter'] = $scope.filter.filterDefinition;
    }
    $scope.restoreFilter = function () {
        $scope.filter.filterDefinition = localStorage['filter'];
    }

    // update filter type for "downloads" column
    $scope.$watch('downloadsColumnFilterType', function () {
        var f = $scope.filter;
        if (f) {
            var col = f.grid.columns.getColumn('downloads'),
                cf = f.getColumnFilter(col, true);
            cf.filterType = $scope.downloadsColumnFilterType;
        }
    });

    // filters are localizable
    $scope.culture = 'en';
    $scope.$watch('culture', function () {

        // remove old localization reference
        var loc = document.getElementById('loc');
        if (loc) {
            document.head.removeChild(loc);
        }

        // add new localization reference
        loc = document.createElement('script');
        loc.id = 'loc';
        loc.type = 'text/javascript';
        loc.async = false;
        loc.src = 'scripts/vendor/wijmo.culture.' + $scope.culture + '.js';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(loc);

        // show changes
        invalidateAll();
    });

    // invalidate all Wijmo controls
    // using a separate function to handle strange IE9 scope issues
    function invalidateAll() {
        wijmo.Control.invalidateAll();
    }

    // create some random data
    var countries = 'US,Germany,UK,Japan,Italy,Greece'.split(','),
        data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        data.push({
            id: i,
            date: new Date(2015, i % 12, (i + 1) % 25),
            time: new Date(2015, i % 12, (i + 1) % 25, i % 24, i % 60, i % 60),
            country: countries[i % countries.length],
            countryMapped: i % countries.length,
            downloads: Math.round(Math.random() * 20000),
            sales: Math.random() * 10000,
            expenses: Math.random() * 5000,
            checked: i % 9 == 0
        });
    }
    $scope.data = new wijmo.collections.CollectionView(data);

    // notify scope when collectionView changes
    $scope.data.collectionChanged.addHandler(function () {
        if (!$scope.$root.$$phase) {
            $scope.$apply();
        }
    });

    // expose countries, country map
    $scope.countries = countries;
    var countryMap = [
        { name: 'US', key: 0 },
        { name: 'Germany', key: 1 },
        { name: 'Japan', key: 2 },
        { name: 'Italy', key: 3 },
        { name: 'Greece', key: 4 },
        { name: 'Spain', key: 5 },
        { name: 'Chile', key: 6 },
        { name: 'China', key: 7 },
        { name: 'Canada', key: 8 },
        { name: 'Astralia', key: 9 },
        { name: 'Austria', key: 10 }
    ];
    $scope.countryMap = new wijmo.grid.DataMap(new wijmo.collections.CollectionView(countryMap), 'key', 'name');

    $scope.buttonClick = function() {
      if(!$scope.ctx.grid) return;
      console.log($scope.ctx.grid.selectedItems);
    };

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
     <!-- Wijmo -->
     <script src="http://demos.wijmo.com/5/Angular/FlexGridFilter/FlexGridFilter/scripts/vendor/wijmo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="http://demos.wijmo.com/5/Angular/FlexGridFilter/FlexGridFilter/scripts/vendor/wijmo.grid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="http://demos.wijmo.com/5/Angular/FlexGridFilter/FlexGridFilter/scripts/vendor/wijmo.grid.filter.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  
    <script src="http://demos.wijmo.com/5/Angular/FlexGridFilter/FlexGridFilter/scripts/vendor/wijmo.input.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  
    <link href="http://demos.wijmo.com/5/Angular/FlexGridFilter/FlexGridFilter/styles/vendor/wijmo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Wijmo-Angular interop -->
    <script src="http://demos.wijmo.com/5/Angular/FlexGridFilter/FlexGridFilter/scripts/vendor/wijmo.angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
    
    
    
  </head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
 
       <button ng-click="buttonClick()">Log Selected Data Items</button>
        <wj-flex-grid
            control="ctx.grid"
            style="height:300px"
            initialized="initialized(s, e)"
            items-source="data">
                <wj-flex-grid-column header="ID" binding="id"></wj-flex-grid-column>
                <wj-flex-grid-column header="Date" binding="date" format='MMM/dd/yyyy'></wj-flex-grid-column>
                <wj-flex-grid-column header="Time" binding="time" format="t"></wj-flex-grid-column>
                <wj-flex-grid-column header="Country" binding="country"></wj-flex-grid-column>
                <wj-flex-grid-column header="Country ID" binding="countryMapped" data-map="countryMap"></wj-flex-grid-column>
                <wj-flex-grid-column header="Downloads" binding="downloads"></wj-flex-grid-column>
                <wj-flex-grid-column header="Sales" binding="sales"></wj-flex-grid-column>
                <wj-flex-grid-column header="Expenses" binding="expenses"></wj-flex-grid-column>
                <wj-flex-grid-column header="Checked" binding="checked"></wj-flex-grid-column>
        </wj-flex-grid>
      
        
         
         
    </div>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You must add your own html code **selection-changed="selectionChanged()"**

```
 <wj-flex-grid   style="height:300px"
        initialized="initialized(s, e)"
        items-source="data"  selection-changed="selectionChanged(s,e)">
    <wj-flex-grid-column [width]="'*'" [header]="'نام کاتالوگ'" [binding]="'Description'" [dataType]="'String'">
    </wj-flex-grid-column>
  </wj-flex-grid>
```

And add the method in the controller

```
$scope.selectionChanged = function (s, e) {
    var flex = s;
}
```